# 'Total' in ls -lsh in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, ls

I'm trying to output only files size to a file using ls -lsh command. But it is displaying total as well. **I need something like:** 
 
 . ./sample.txt    4.0K
 
 ./multisample.txt
4.0K 
 **But it is displaying as follows**: 
 . ./test.txt ./multitest.txt 
4.0K 
4.0K

.:
total
4.0K
4.0K
4.0K

 Commands I've used are: ls -lsh $LISTNAME |awk '{print $1}'   >> /home/test/$date.log 
 where $LISTNAME contains file names. 
 Please let me know how to display only file size and also in the format I need (File name1 **tab** filesize and in next line filename2 **tab** filesize)

Comment: Are you aware that filenames can contain tab characters?

Comment: Frankly, the most reliable / least buggy way to do this without writing your own code for changing numbers to human-readable values yourself (which is how I've done this in the past) is a separate `du -sh` call per input file, then extracting only the size component of output. It's messy and inefficient, but it gets you out of the business of parsing filenames. (Also, modern GNU `du` supports a `-0` argument, which helps greatly with disambiguation).

Answer (score 3):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Best way to do that, although it gives you size in bytes, is:

```
# this assumes your filenames don't contain whitespace
stat -c $'%n\t%s' $LISTNAME
```

If $LISTNAME is a newline-separated list of files, this will accomodate spaces and/or tabs in the filenames, but not newlines. Assumes bash (version 4 I think)

```
mapfile -t files <<<"$LISTNAME"
stat -c $'%n\t%s' "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: It is just displaying filesize as numbers. I need to have something like 5K or 5G.    Above command outputs as:  ./test.txt      4
./multitest.txt 5

Answer (score 0):

Provided you understand and accept that this will **break** if any filename contains any whitespace character, this command does what you were trying to do:

```
ls -1sh | awk '!/^total / { print $2 "\t" $1 }'
```

If you need to handle filenames containing whitespace you are probably going to be happier writing a perl or python script that uses OS primitives to list the directory and get the size of each file.

Comment: If I use above command it gave output as :  ./test.txt 4.0K
./multitest.txt      4.0K

        .:   ./test.txt   4.0K
./multitest.txt        4.0K  --> Displaying twice. Please help me on this.

Comment: Please ask a new question about that.

Comment: I've included this issue in my question. Please let me know how to eliminate these duplicates.

Comment: Please ask a *new* question specifically about the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bash (not `/bin/sh`) and GNU `du`:

```
# Collect a list of files (not directories, to prevent recursion)
files=( ); for f in *; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && files+=( "$f" ); done

while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
  filename=${line#*$'\t'}
  size=${line%%$'\t'*}
  printf '%q\t%s\n' "$filename" "$size"
done < <(du -0sh --apparent-size "${files[@]}")
```

Because this uses `printf %q`, it will write filenames with spaces, tab characters, or even newlines in unambiguous, eval-safe form. For instance:

```
CHECKSUMS       4.0K
exit-trap       4.0K
$'file with a tab here:\t and a newline here:\n'        1.0K
```

...if instead you want to write those characters literally (with the obvious effect on ability to unambiguously parse the file's contents), simply replace the `%q` with a `%s`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
ls -lh | awk '{print $9 "\t" $5}'
```

Comment: The standard for `ls -l` doesn't guarantee that any column past the time will be at a specific location when reading output as space-delimited. Also, `$9` won't correctly handle names with whitespace in this usage.